# Update tables depending on parameter value MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm having a bad day and can't think of an answer to this...

On my form I have a number of inputs, I'm updating some of them back to the database when the Save button is pressed. My issue I'm thinking is.

How can I match the Input field which I have stored as a parameter and check to see if this differs from what is already input or if the field is null then update with the parameter value, and another parameter value is x for example how can I update another table?

As an example my form has name, telephone, rented/owned, house type & notes. When I click the Save button these values will be pushed into a Procedure using IN parameters. I've updated fields in the table with the values which is great but, is there a way to check that the parameter value is different than what is in the table already and update this. As I don't want to update all the fields if they don't need to be. Also say rented/owned parameter was rented then is there a way to update a different table.

How is it possible to write in the procedure if parameter x = rented update table A else update table B?

Comment: Why do you care about updating values that are already there? Also, why not test to see if this is really what happens anyway?

Comment: You can probably accomplish it with an update-join and `CASE` logic, but please post your existing procedure and the table structures.